# Grounding Class I device

Tags: power-supply

I'm designing a IEC Class I device with requirement of grounding the chassis. The device use a AC power supply with V- and V+ outputs.

How should I connect the ground of the internal circuit? Should it float (connect to V- of the power supply) or is it OK to connect V- with the chassis that share AC ground?

Comment: Take a look at most measurement equipment, for example an oscilloscope. There the circuit ground and mains ground are shorted, so yes you are allowed connect the internal ground to mains ground. In a lab supply it is different, the DC outputs will not be connected to ground. So leaving the circuit unconnected to mains ground is an option as well. It depends on the kind of equipment I guess.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You forgot the word "good" before lab supply.

Comment: What is this device? The answers are different if this is a washing machine v. a piece of high quality audio gear.